# Retain selection highlight after copying text to clipboard in tmux

Tags: tmux, mouse, clipboard, highlighting

I'm using macOS and `tmux 3.1c`. When copying a text via mouse selection, the highlight will be auto-cleared after copying the text to clipboard, this will make it difficult to keep track the last line you copied when you go back to it:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent/disable the auto-clearing of selection after copying? I know about pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then selecting the text, and then hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard, which preserves the selection. But this is relatively inefficient workflow. This is the same behavior with Alacritty/iTerm.

In iTerm, **without tmux**, selecting a text will auto-copy it in the clipboard, but the selection will not be auto-cleared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `copy-selection-no-clear` command.

For example, if you are using vi mode, you can define `y` to copy the selection without clearing it:

```
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi y send -X copy-selection-no-clear
```

For emacs use the `copy-mode` table.

Comment: Exactly what I want! Ended up with `bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send -X copy-selection-no-clear` since I usually use the mouse for selection, and it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: @RanelPadon glad this helped. don't forget to accept the answer so your question no longer shows up in the unanswered section.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean of "accept the answer"? I already upvoted your answer. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that I could accept an answer also, I should have done this even before in my StackOverflow posts. Although some of them, I ended up the one who solved it also. Cheers
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers